# Work around to use two unique keys on partitioned table

Tags: mysql, partitioning

We have a dataset of roughly 400M rows, 200G in size. 200k rows are added in a daily batch. It mainly serves as an archive that is indexed for full text search by another application.

In order to reduce the database footprint, the data is stored in plain myIsam.

We are considering a range-partitioned table to streamline the backup process, but cannot figure a good way to handle unique keys. We absolutely need two of them. One to be directly compatible with the rest of the schema (ex: custId), another to be compatible with the full text search app (ex: seqId).

My understanding is that partitions do not support more than one globally unique key. We would have to merge both unique keys (custId, seqId), which will not work in our case.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Trying with custID as PK and seqID as auto-incremented KEY. Not ideal but should work.

Comment: A MySQL partitioned table does not support _any_ `UNIQUE` keys _unless_ the "partition key" is part of the unique key.

Comment: Don't worry about UNIQUE keys unless you _need_ to get a "duplicate key error".  Show us the `CREATE TABLE` so we can talk more specifically.